# OpenLayers 3 - Div on top of map is not capturing click

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

I have a form/div displayed on top of the map. I want to make it so that it is hidden when there is a click outside the form/div area but not when the click is inside the form/div.

I can't get to detect when the click is done inside the div. Instead all clicks inside the form/div are detected as done on the map, as if the div doesn't exist.

```
<div id="map"  class="map"><div id="popup">
//input data of form
</div>  </div>


<script>
 map.on('click', function(evt) {
  console.log('Clicked #map');
          //one method I tried from another stack overflow answer 
           (evt.target !== this) ? $("#popup").show() : $popup.hide();

        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
            function(feature) {
              return feature;
            });

        if (feature) {
          loadInfo(feature.get('id'));
          $("#popup").show();
        } 
      });

$("popup").on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Clicked #popup');
});
    </script>
```

**Output**

> Clicked #map
>
> Clicked #popup

As you can see in the code I tried few different methods on detecting clicks on the popup but none of them worked. All of them are as if, the popup is not even there.

I am using openlayers3 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to prevent further propagation of the current `click` event in the capturing and bubbling phases:

```js
var $map = $('#map'),
    $popup = $('#popup');

$map.on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Clicked #map');
  (e.target !== this) ? $popup.show() : $popup.hide();
});

$popup.on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Clicked #popup');
});
```

```css
#map {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 80%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 40px;
}

#popup {
  background-color:  #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"  class="map">
  <div id="popup">
    // input data of form
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to write this answer, but it doesn't work. The popup disappears whether I click inside the popup or outside.

Comment: If you click in the `#map` the `#popup` should disappear.. But if you click in the `#popup` it should keep visible.. Is it right?

Comment: Correct. It still doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the map being a canvas.

Comment: You right, the event was bubbling and firing the #map click event.. Check now

Comment: Even after e.stopPropagation() it still detects a click at #map. From the log it appears that the click is always detected first at Map and then at the popup. It really puzzles me.

Comment: As you can see in the example i have added works because logs in console.. Can you add an example in your question as you have now in your application?

Comment: Also it appears that the div is not solid over the map area. So all the mouse movements and click go through to the map area, even if they are done on top of the popup. If there is a marker hidden by the popup the click will go through and activate the other marker.

Comment: I edited my answer. to make it more clear. It should work with simple divs but I am using OpenLayers, so it changes the map div into a canvas during execution.

Comment: Check that in your code `$("popup")` is different from `$("#popup")`... Make the variables and use them please and also make `$map`